# What is the name of the song that plays at 12:40 in Noragami Aragoto episode 12?

Tags: music, noragami

What is the name of the song that plays at 12:40 in Noragami Aragoto episode 12? It has a distorted female(?) voice and a flute themes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "Misogi", track #11 from the [season 1 OST](http://vgmdb.net/album/43077). The piece starts right after the eyecatch. Here is a 15-second extract from the beginning of the piece: https://clyp.it/i1altiyi.